# Unable to delete folder in 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I am create .ssh folder in windows and tried to some combinations of permissions on that folder after that tried to enter or delete the folder but unable do it giving below errors.
When i am trying to delete the it is giving the error:"drive is full or used by some other user."
When i am trying to enter into the directory it is giving the message:"Access denied"

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that no process is using the file that was created, which in your case, it sounds like there is. If you're sure that nothing is using or locking the file, then try seizing ownership of the file with an account with sufficient privileges to do so (ie administrator).

Answer (score 1):

As DKNUCKLES already stated: The file object must not be in use. You can get that information via a sysinternals tool named "handle.exe". 
You can donwload handel.exe here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896655

If this fileobject is in use by an network client you get that via "Administrativ tolls" -> Computer Management in "Systems Tools" -> "Shared Folders" - "Open Files"

THT